# jQuery UI Customized Tabs breaking layout

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-tabs

I am having this strange issue with jQuery UI Tabs.

I am using the Widget for a Featured news section in a newspaper website.

My index section works perfectly well, but when I enter some site section, something happens and the tab layout just breaks and the page gets cycled and for some reason displays sort of iframes of the same page all over which makes it unusable.

Here's the live version:

Index (working section): [Index](http://puntomedio.ofertascancun.net/)

Specific section (broken): [Specific Section](http://puntomedio.ofertascancun.net/internacional/)

Script versions I'm using:

```
<link href="css/puntomedio/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker-es.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

I personalize the css in my main css file [CSS File](http://puntomedio.ofertascancun.net/css/estilos.css), you can find the entries under the /* Complementarios de jQuery */ comment.

The initializing script for the tabs is:

```
<? // <script src="js/jquery.ui.tabs.rotate.js"></script> ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $(".titulares").tabs(/* { hide: { effect: "slide", duration: 200 }, show: { effect: "slide", duration: 200 } } */).addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix")//.tabs("rotate", 5000, false);
    //$(".titulares li").removeClass("ui-tabs ui-widget").addClass("ui-corner-left");
});
</script>
```

There are some things commented as I am not using them at the moment.

I tried switching jQuery and jQuery UI version without any success.

Console isn't showing any error.

Any idea what could be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

Another question I answer on my own... apparently jQuery tabs and the base tag don't get along so well... so I had to remove the base tag and change my links all over.

Found this article if anyone is interested: http://tjvantoll.com/2013/02/17/using-jquery-ui-tabs-with-the-base-tag/